# How to exclude "+" from being treated as special character in NSRegularExpression?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I have a following `userName`: `iphone6s_taylor` and `iphone6+_taylor`.

to find them in text I have created following regular expression:

```
let regex = "\\B@\(userName)\\b"
```

But within the following text:

```
let text = "@iphone6s_taylor @iphone6+_taylor @iphone6+_taylor"
```

only the first one is found. How to change the regex to find every of them?

Comment: have you tried replace + with \\+ first?

Comment: Actually I cannot replace any characters in text, because not every of `+`'s should be replaced.

Comment: That case, I don't think there's anyway else except you pre-process the userName to the correct pattern.

Comment: `let text = "\\B@\(NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString(userName))\\b"`

Comment: Isn't that still replace ALL + to \\+?

Comment: I didnt know that there is such awesome method for this:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`escapedPatternForString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRegularExpression/escapedPatternForString:):

> Returns a string by adding backslash escapes as necessary to the given string, to escape any characters that would otherwise be treated as pattern metacharacters.

Sample usage for your scenario:

```
let userName = NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString("iphone6+_taylor")
```

Comment: It works great. Can you simplify your answer to `let userName = NSRegularExpression.escapedPatternForString("iphone6+_taylor")`? Then I will accept this:)

Comment: If you do not like sample solutions in the answer, I will just keep a link here. See [Swift demo](http://swiftstub.com/175585950/) returning `@iphone6+_taylor`. If these links expire, I will just remove the comment. :)

Comment: @stribizhev: There is no problem with sample solutions in the answer, and of course I don't know where you got that method from. But *if* you copied it from another answer then you should add a link to the original, for proper attribution.

Comment: Actually, I keep those helper functions locally, and forget to include source links often :( I have a modified version of that function that returns all matches and all submatches for each match, but I guess that is a different story.